# additional IP addresses for bonded network cards

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, bonding

I configured a bond of two network cards, I set an IP address and it works great.

Then I configured an additional IP address for each card, and these addresses doesn't work. The problem is that the computer doesn't accept any incoming traffic on this addresses ( It seems it doesn't respond to ARP requests firstly). These addresses are not visible by other computers in the network

The configuration is:

```
root@NanoPi-R1:~# ip -4 a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.3.19/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.2.19/24 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.4.19/24 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



root@NanoPi-R1:~# ip r s
192.168.2.0/24 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.19 
192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.19 
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.4.19 


root@NanoPi-R1:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: de:74:32:46:b5:ed
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 02:81:3a:01:ac:6b
Slave queue ID: 0
```

The 192.168.2.19 address works perfectly, but the two other addresses are not visible in the network. Dears please help.

[Design of the network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdvRd.jpg)

The subnetwork 192.168.2.* is needed to inter-node cluster communication.

Answer (score 1):

These addresses are not **supposed** to work: The slave interfaces `eth0` and `eth1` are now part of the bonded connection and can't have their own addresses.

This is similar to when you make network interfaces ports of a bridge. Those interfaces can't have their own address as well.

You can still set addresses with `ip addr` etc., but they just get ignored.

You *can* set multiple IP addresses to the master interface (in your case, `bond0`), though. But this may not be what you want (actually, you didn't explain what you want and why you want to do it that way).

Comment: Thx for the response, I have added the network topology drawing. The bond is needed to reliable communication between cluster nodes. The single interfaces are used to communication with equipment. Each of the equipment is reachable only by one NIC ( Don't count on HUB 3) so if I used the bond to communicate with the equipment the transmission could be placed on the other NIC, which doesn't have connection with the equipment and the packet would be lost.